# Rails - Chewy Reset only a set o records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I am using chewy in as Ruby wrapper to the elasticsearch client.

My question is about `reset` only a set of records. With `import` I can use:

`UsersIndex::User.import User.where('rating > 100')`

Is possible use something like:

`UsersIndex.reset User.where('rating > 100')`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `reset` will destroy the index, so it will have to reconstruct it entirely.

Maybe in your case you don't want to reconstruct it entirely, so you just want to update the index of your records right ?
You can do it that way:

`UserIndex.update_index(id: User.where(rating > 100).pluck(:id))`